# Text cuts off from the bottom when usibg Bootstrap 5 "sign in form" example

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

So I am currently trying to follow a guide that helps me to understand bootstrap and using it better.
Currently, I am trying to modify a [Sign in template provided by Bootstrap Example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/sign-in/), but and I had success doing it - i.e, changing the fields so they match what I want them to be.

However, I noticed that both in their example template and in my page, the text cuts off at the bottom. For example, whenever I type "g, @" it just cuts off at the bottom.

This is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.form-signin .form-floating:focus-within {
  z-index: 2;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.middle {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.bottom {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Sign up Page</title>
</head>
<body class="text-center d-flex align-items-center py-4 bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin w-100 m-auto" method="post" action="/">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="72" height="72" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-airplane-engines" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.347 4.347 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0ZM7 3c0-.432.11-.979.322-1.401C7.542 1.159 7.787 1 8 1c.213 0 .458.158.678.599C8.889 2.02 9 2.569 9 3v4a.5.5 0 0 0 .276.447l5.448 2.724a.5.5 0 0 1 .276.447v.792l-5.418-.903a.5.5 0 0 0-.575.41l-.5 3a.5.5 0 0 0 .14.437l.646.646H6.707l.647-.646a.5.5 0 0 0 .14-.436l-.5-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.576-.411L1 11.41v-.792a.5.5 0 0 1 .276-.447l5.448-2.724A.5.5 0 0 0 7 7V3Z"/>
              </svg>
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Newsletter Sign Up</h1>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control top" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First name">
                <label for="lastName">First Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control middle" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control bottom" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
                <label for="Email">Email</label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-3" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-body-secondary">©2023 By Yuval</p>
          </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to modify form-floating and form-control and their height or line height, but with no success.

I ran that website on my thinkpad t480s, on fedora, using google chrome with a 1080P screen with 100% scaling. I noticed that when I scale the website to be larger or even smaller the issue go away. How can I solve it so it will work on every font size?

Thanks very much for every help provided!

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Those text characters look perfect on the input fields in my computer. I tried on different browsers and different screen resolutions, still the same.